# How to make function composition when i have list of functions in python?

Tags: python

So i want to make function composition with the list. I have done function which compose two functions into one and calculate value of this.

This function:

```
def zad6_1(f, g, x):
    return f(g(x))
```

In the next step i want to use this function to compose function with the list I tried to use reduce but I think i messed up in here.

This is my creation:

```
def zad6(l, x):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: zad6_1(f, g, x), l[0:], l[1:])
```

My main problem is that I don't know what I should place instead of two argument after lambda function.
Of course if there is better solution than reduce, please show me that.

There is an example:

```
l6 = [lambda x: x**2+1, lambda x: x**3, lambda x: x+1, lambda x: 4*x]
```

That is my input list the from the left function a(x),b(x),c(x),d(x).
I want to make something like this a(b(c(d(x)))).

https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/functions-composition.html
I talk about this.
PS. I cannot use loop and comperhension

Comment: Unclear, needs an example.

Comment: Why can't you use loops and comprehensions? Is this some sort of assignment?

Comment: 1. I'll add example in minutes.
2. Yes, it's part of task in my high school

Comment: Do you truly need function composition, i.e., compute a function object that's the composition of given functions? Or do you just need to compute a result value, given functions and an input value?

Comment: @KellyBundy I just need result vaule of the this compostion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reduce` function generally takes 2 arguments, a function (often a lambda), and a sequence. Sometimes you also want to provide a third argument, an initializer (initial value). You are providing more arguments.

Simple example of using reduce:

```py
from functools import reduce

answer = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, [0, 1, 2]) # a is the accumulated value and b the current value

print(answer) # prints 3
```

Here, `lambda a, b: a+b` is the function, and `[0, 1, 2]` is the sequence provided to the `reduce` function. Reduce will go over the sequence and execute the (lambda) function at every step. At every step the current value of the sequence and the accumulated value (from previous steps) are provided to the lambda function.

[See the documentation on reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: def zad6(l, x):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: zad6_1(f, g, x), l) it is stil doesn't work there is an error TypeError: 'int' object is not callable